# Stack Overflow Markdown CSS for text editors

Tags: discussion, design, markdown

Certain text editors (e.g. [Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)) allow you to customise the preview of the markdown with CSS.

There is CSS available for GitHub Markdown Style e.g. https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css

Is there a Markdown Style for how Stack Overflow presents it?

I had a look at the [page source](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css), but it is pretty big, and I couldn't tease it out.

Comment: I think that this question could be approved but not in StackOverflow but in StackMeta. Maybe is possible to move it?

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree. Probably better on meta.

Comment: So just to be certain, you're asking for Stack Overflow's Markdown CSS rules?

Comment: Did you ever find them?

Comment: I haven't found them yet :(

Answer (score -1):

It seems that there is no progress made in the last five years.

I hope this gets more attention, so we get this feature soon.

Here is my explanation of the "problem":

If you want to style your answer in the comment or about page etc., you would try this for example:

```markdown
![rofflecopter](https://media1.tenor.com/images/13ab077a4ba351925ccba299db5bd9b1/tenor.gif?itemid=5225406 "ROFL COPTER")

<style>
img[title="ROFL COPTER"] {
   filter: invert(89%);
}
</style>
```

But this does not work on Stack Overflow. On other sites, like GitHub or other Markdown previews, it's possible to do so. I would also like to see this future in Stack Overflow.

Comment: What do you mean by *"in the like comment"*?

Comment: Sorry for my bad englisch. I edited it :D